# Calculating dependency of two time series variables

Tags: time-series

I have two different hourly measurement datasets. Other is temperature, and other is some measured value. I am interested to study how temperature affects the other value and eventually find a coefficient that I can use to "normalize" the measurement data to normal temperature. I also want to consider the lag effect of temperature. I am using python for the analysis and I already tried linear regression, but get extremely poor results, for example R-squared values. I already calculated a strong correlation between the values, and found best lag value using this correlation